# PTIJ: Why didn't Haman just kill all the Jews in Russia?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Before, and perhaps while, Haman was Achashveirosh's viceroy he was the Tsar of Russia, as it says in [Esther 7:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16480#v=6):

> וַתֹּאמֶר אֶסְתֵּר--אִישׁ צַר וְאוֹיֵב, הָמָן הָרָע הַזֶּה;
>
> And Ester said, a man, the Tsar, an enemy -- this evil Haman!

Since Haman was Tsar, why didn't he put his nefrarious plan into action there and then, when Mordechai and Ester weren't around to foil it?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: And here I thought Haman **was** Russia (Rasha), not just its leader!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mistranslating. "צַר" doesn't mean "tsar" but is, rather, the masculine form of the word "צָרָה", "[co-wife](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-wife)", and thus means "co-husband". That is, *Ester* was pointing out to *Achashverosh* that not only was *Haman* the one who was plotting to kill *Ester*'s people (see the context there), *Haman* also had shared a wife with *Achashverosh*, namely *Vashti*.

*Achashverosh* was not angered by the latter revelation, since he was, as we know, licentious himself. He was, however, angry about the attempt on *Ester*'s co-nationals' lives, and stood up for a walk in the garden. When he returned to the party, the following verses tell us,

> *Haman* was falling on the chaise longue that *Esther* was on.

*Haman* saw that it didn't bother *Achashverosh* that they had shared a previous wife, so decided to try the same with *Ester*. But

> the king said, "Do you plan also to conquer the queen with me at home?"

and had him killed. You see, sharing a wife was no big deal for *Achashverosh*; what bothered him was sharing a home. He was not only licentious but inhospitable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that you didn't find the answer directly in the verse that you cited. It says:

אִישׁ צַר וְאוֹיֵב הָמָן הָרָע הַזֶּה

A czar and an enemy, Haman who is this bad.

He was a bad czar. Meaning, he was a weak czar. He wasn't strong enough to be a czar in the first place, but for some reason, probably a political favor, Achashverush made him a czar.

Thus, Esther was pointing out to Achashevrush Haman's weakness by saying, essentially, "Yes, he is an enemy and a czar, but he's very bad at his job."